# Hover effect making other elements move

Tags: html, css, image, hover

can anyone help. 
I have an image of a butterfly that pops out a little when hovered over. I also have an image of a caterpillar. the trouble is that when the butterfly is hovered over the other image is also moving. how can i stop this?

The CSS is

```
/*Pink Butterfly - header*/
.pinkbutterfly  {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;   
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top:-30px;
    left:230px;
    }

.hoverimg:hover{
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
    position: relative;
    top:-30px;
    left:220px;
    }

/*Blue/Yellow Caterpillar - header*/
.blueyellowcaterpillar{
    width: 140px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top:30px;
    left:550px
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="headercontent"> 
  <img src="nurserylogo.png" alt="Cassiltoun Stables Nursery Logo" class="nurserylogo">
  <img src="Edited Characters/pinkbutterfly.png" alt="pinkbutterfly" class="pinkbutterfly hoverimg">
  <img src="Edited Characters/blueyellowcaterpillar.png" alt="blueyellowcaterpillar" class="blueyellowcaterpillar choverimg">
  <p style="font-family:'FeltTip'">Tel: 0141 631 5235</p>
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul class="navlist"> 
      <li> about </li>
      <li> pictures </li>
      <li> find us </li>
      <li> contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `class="blueyellowcaterpillar choverimg">` be `class="blueyellowcaterpillar hoverimg">`.  Also, you should tag this with `css`.

Comment: I changed it because the caterpillar image needs to do the same effect but with different settings. It's more just the getting the butterfly to move without interrupting anything else on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the size of the element makes the layout rearrange.

To make it greater without afecting the layout, try

```
.hoverimg:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale (1.2);
    transform: scale (1.2);
}
```

That should make it bigger, keeping it centered in the previous position.
If this is not what you want, add

```
    -webkit-transform-origin (top, center);
    transform-origin (top, center);
```